# how to replace variables in a string in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I am working on a Beanshell preprocessor and I need to replace the values ​​into my "String" to assign the parameter values (json format), I have this

```
String textToSign = 
"{ \"origin\": \"${origin_encrypted}\"," +
"  \"destiny\": \"${destiny_encrypted}\"," +
"  \"subject\": \"${subject_encrypted}\"," +
"  \"amount\": \"${amount_encrypted}\"," +
"  \"softToken\": \"${softToken_encrypted}\" }";
log.info("Text To Sign: " + textToSign);
```

but i get `Text To Sign: { "origin": "${origin_encrypted}",  "destiny": "${destiny_encrypted}",  "subject": "${subject_encrypted}",  "amount": "${amount_encrypted}",  "softToken": "${softToken_encrypted}" }` 
please help me :(

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should reconsider using Beanshell, [since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting.

Also Groovy provides [more handy way to build JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html) than string concatenation.

```
def payload = [:]

payload.put('origin', vars.get('origin_encrypted'))
payload.put('destiny', vars.get('destiny_encrypted'))
payload.put('subject', vars.get('subject_encrypted'))
payload.put('amount', vars.get('amount_encrypted'))
payload.put('softToken', vars.get('softToken_encrypted'))

String textToSign = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(payload).toPrettyString()

log.info("Text To Sign: " + textToSign)
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)